# Disabling animation on a popup window

Tags: android, window

How can I disable window animations for specific window? (i.e. the same effect as setting Window animation scale" to "off" in the developer options.

```
popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(0);
```

does not seem to do anything.

Thanks,

Comment: "setAnimationStyle(int) in android.widget.PopupWindow cannot be applied to (<nulltype>)"

Answer (score 4):

Try [android.R.style.Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Animation) which is a base style for animations.
Documentation says that this style specifies **no animations**.

```
popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation);
```